# Can NSParameterAssert be left in production code?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Will code with NSParameterAsserts cause apple to reject your app?

Comment: Our apps have not been rejected for this reason.  I make no claims on what will happen with an arbitrary app, but you should be fine on this issue.  Just know that it's a crash for a user where you might be able to otherwise avoid the crash (if the data isn't what you expect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSParameterAsserts does not run in Release mode by default. I had the bad experience of leaving code to be executed in an NSParameterAsserts([obj method]) which caused the app to crash in release and work perfectly in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

> Assertions are disabled if the preprocessor macro NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is defined. All assertion macros return void.

And it is defined by default in `Release` configuration. So it's ok to leave `NSParameterAsserts` in production.